# Linear Interpolation Algebra not making sense

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Begin with the equation
$$
\dfrac{y-y_0}{x-x_0} = \dfrac{y_1-y_0}{x_1-x_0}
$$

$$
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{y-y_0}{x-x_0} &= \dfrac{y_1-y_0}{x_1-x_0} 
    & \text{Multiply both sides to isolate the lefthand numerator} \\
y-y_0 &= x-x_0 \cdot \dfrac{y_1-y_0}{x_1-x_0}
    & \text{Add y_0 to both sides to isolate y} \\
y &= y_0 + (x-x_0)\dfrac{y_1-y_0}{x_1-x_0}
    & \text{} \\
\end{align*}
$$

Now in the next step i'm struggling to produce the correct output, which i've gotten from the wikipedia article:
[image: Imgge from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation]

I've done the following and produced a partial output, but i seem to be missing some terms from the fraction on the lefthand side of the second step in the picture

see my working:

$$
\begin{align*}
y       &= y_0 + \dfrac{x-x_0}{1} \dfrac{y_1-y_0}{x_1-x_0}
                & \text{} \\
        &= y_0 + \dfrac{(y_1-y_0)(x-x_0)}{x_1-x_0}
                & \text{} \\
        &= y_0 + \dfrac{y_1(x-x_0)-y_0(x-x_0)}{x_1-x_0}
                & \text{} \\
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: When you distribute you should carry along the negative sign in front of $y_0$ making a $-y_0(x-x_0)$ term.

Comment: @DougM - yes. sorry. i've updated the question, that wan't the issue i was running into

Comment: The lefthand term on the second step on the wiki article $$\frac{y0(x1-x0){x1-x0}$$ is the missing terms

Comment: The algebra on the wiki article looks fine to me.  From the first to the second step $y_0$ becomes $\frac {y_0(x_1-x_0)}{(x_1-x0)}$ to give it the same common denominator as the terms that follow.

Comment: Ohh, I see, ty. They have just multiplied the dividend in the leftmost fraction by the divisor in the right hand fraction, then divided by that common factor, to make them compatible or to allow them to be added. THANK YOU.

Comment: $$
\begin{align*}
y   &= \dfrac{y0(x1-x0)}{x1-x0} + \dfrac{y1(x-x0)-y0(x-x0)}{x1-x0}
        & \text{}
\end{align*}
$$ Common denominator, not factor.